# Determine probability with model accuracy

Tags: probability, self-study, classification, accuracy

I was given today with this question:

product x represents 2% of the sales volume

Binary Classification model, result 1 if the model predicts that a buyer will buy product x, result 0 if the model predicts that a buyer will not buy product x.

For buyers of product x, the model is correct 98% of the time

For non buyers of product x, the model is correct 98% of the time

The model predicts 1 for a specific costumer.

What is the probability of this customer to be a product x buyer?

I don't even know where to start for calculating this, since I thought that the answer would have been 98%, but unfortunately is wrong.

Comment: Are you familiar with Bayes’s rule? Please tag this question with [tag:self-study] and follow the instructions in its tag wiki.

Comment: tag added, but I don't know where to start to apply Bayes's rule

Comment: P(buyer | predicted to be a buyer) is your target…how would you apply Bayes here?

Comment: Suppose you had 1 million people.  How many would you expect to actually be buyers and non-buyers?  Of these, how many would you expect to be predicted as buyers?  Of those predicted to be buyers, how many would you expect to actually be buyers?

Comment: We’re given p(predict-is-buyer | is-buyer) and p(predict-is-not-buyer | is-not-buyer), and we’re now asked for p(is-buyer | predict-is-buyer). Write out the rule.

Comment: Get away from the idea of classification and use a direct probability model such as logistic regression.

Comment: @Henry so:
2% of the market, so out of 1m people, I'm expecting that 20.000 people it's going to buy it.
98% of them are going to be predicted as buyers, so 19.600 people predicted.
Of those predicted to be buyers, how many would you expect to actually be buyers? I'm stuck at this point

Comment: so you expect 980,000 not to buy.  How many of those not buying would you expect were predicted to buy?  How many in total predicted to buy?

Comment: Out of those 980.000 I'm expecting 98% to be predicted as not buyers, so 2% as buyers.
That means that the answer of the question is 19.600 + 19.600? = 40.000 that is 4%, is that right?